# How to import package modules as __main__ aliases inside __init__.py?

Tags: python

I would like to import all modules inside a package as aliases in __main__ using __init__.py so they can be called simply from interactive mode. For example, here is a sample file tree:

```
foobar/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

and from the python interpreter I want to be able to import the package and have access to all modules using defined aliases like this:

```
>>> import foobar
>>> <module 'foobar' from 'C:\...'>
>>> f.func()
>>> b.func()
```

This will require __init__.py to contain something along the lines of:

```
# __init__.py

from . import foo as f
from . import bar as b

# these will not work
__main__.f = f
__main__.b = b
```

How can I make this work?

**EDIT**

I don't want to use `from foobar import *` because it will not allow me to use aliasing.

Typing `from foobar import foo as f` for every module, every time I start interactive mode is not efficient because there could be hundreds of modules.

Comment: What are you doing in interactive mode that involves importing hundreds of modules? It seems like you're creating your own problems if that's part of your workflow. You could always create just one module that imports all the others (with aliases if desired), then import from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very bad behavior for a module to add things to a separate module's namespace without being explicitly told to do so. [Explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), as they say.

I suggest you avoid anything complicated in your `__init__.py` and simply do this in your main module (or on the command line):

```
import foobar.foo as f, foobar.bar as b
```

**Edit:**

It is possible to mess around with the main module if you really need to. While it's probably not a good idea, here's how:

```
import sys

import foo, bar

main = sys.modules["__main__"]
main.f = foo
main.b = bar
```

Now, as several people have said, its usually not a good idea to make importing a module have side effects like that. At the very least, anyone else who ever reads your code will be tremendously confused. "Wait, where did this `f` variable come from?"

Instead of making your module insert things into your global namespace, what I suggest is that you have it do the aliasing you want in its own namespace, and then use `from module import *` on it to get the aliases in your namespace.

Make `foobar`'s `__init__.py` file look like this:

```
from . import foo as f
from . import bar as b
```

Then in your main module, just do:

```
from foobar import *
# now you can use f and b
```

If you have hundreds of imports to do, put them all in `__init__.py`. Or if they're not associated with that package, use a separate module to handle the aliasing stuff.

Comment: So there is no way to import modules into `__main__` without typing into the interactive prompt?

Comment: I suspect it is possible, but if so it would be a horrible hack. I strongly doubt it is worth it, just to avoid a little extra typing. If you want aliases, ask for them explicitly!

Comment: Let's say there are 100 modules I need to import every time is start up the Python interactive prompt. I'm not just trying to avoid "a little" extra typing.

Comment: @redreceipt: I've expanded my answer, to both do what you say you want to do, and to give an alternative that will be much nicer to anyone else who tries to read and understand it.

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what I needed. I agree that your second method is much nicer, but like most developed code, mine comes with requirements from higher authorities. Nevertheless, I will make a push to use the safer, more coherent solution. PS, would you move your comment in my main question to this comment thread. It doesn't make any sense without context to other readers.

Answer (score 3):

In your __init__.py file include something like:

```
import foo
import bar as b
```

Then in the interactive session use:

```
>>> from foobar import *
>>> value = foo.some_func()
>>> instance = b.SomeClass()
```

I should also mention that `from foobar import *` is considered bad style by most python programers, and while that doesn't matter in an interactive session, if you wanted to accomplish the same thing in a module or script the preferred way would be:

```
from foobar import b, foo
```

Comment: `from foobar import *` will only work if `__all__` is defined in `__init__.py`. And it will not allow me to use aliases. There are way too many modules to import explicitly and they are constantly changing. This is why I want to handle it in `__init__.py`.

Comment: If `__all__` is not present in `__init__.py` everything in `__init__.py` that does not begin with an underscore will be imported by `from foobar import *`.

Comment: Regardless, I don't want to use `from foobar import *` for reasons mentioned previously.

Comment: `from foobar import *` is the mechanism for what you want, it's not clear to me what your precised problem with doing it that way is but based on your question and comments, it's exactly what you need. Maybe you could clarify you question. Also your never going to get the behavior you're asking for by doing `import foobar`, that import statement is only allowed to create one new item in the namespace.

Comment: "And it will not allow me to use aliases." (from above)

Comment: What do you mean by "use aliases" do you mean `import foo as f`? If so you're more then welcome to include that in your `__init__.py` file.

Comment: I agree that is the better solution. Please read my comment to @Blckknght.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply not designated for a Python module to break out of its namespace like that and, because Python effectively tends to restrict everything that is generally not a good idea, it wouldn't be possible. The interactive console might have something like startup hooks, who knows.

Another idea that could make life easier for you: Write into the module:

```
foo = "foo!"
bar = "bar!"

def add_to(obj):
    obj['f'] = foo
    obj['b'] = bar
```

In your interactive console:

```
>>> from stuff import add_to
>>> add_to(globals())
```

Comment: I like that idea. Is there a way to make `__main__.globals()` the default parameter? I understand that it does not exist like that as written.